# How to get SentEvent ID?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

According to the official documentation, the `SentEvent` has an `ID`: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm

But when I send a request like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
        </Options>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
            <Properties>BatchID</Properties>
            <Properties>EventDate</Properties>
            <Properties>EventType</Properties>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I get this:

```xml
<OverallStatus>Error: The Request Property(s) ID do not match with the fields of SentEvent retrieve</OverallStatus>
```

From WSDL, I see that the `SentEvent` extends `TrackingEvent` and the `TrackingEvent` extends `APIObject`:

```xml
<complexType name="APIObject">
  <sequence>
    <element name="Client" type="tns:ClientID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="PartnerKey" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="PartnerProperties" type="tns:APIProperty" minOccurs="0" ma 
 xOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <element name="CreatedDate" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="ModifiedDate" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
    <element name="ID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="ObjectID" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="CustomerKey" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="Owner" type="tns:Owner" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="CorrelationID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="ObjectState" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

The same inheritance I see, say, for `UnsubEvent`, where I can get the `ID` just like in the sample above.

I'd like to understand the following:

- how does it happen that there is an `ID` property in docs and in WSDL, and I can get it for the `UnsubEvent`, but can't get for the `SentEvent` in the same way?
- how can I get the `SentEvent.ID`?

Answer (score 2):

There is an ID on the SentEvent, but it's not "retrievable". If you do a Describe operation (http header "SoapAction" is "Describe") on the SentEvent, or TrackingEvent, you can see the attributes that you can successfully return in the results.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>SentEvent</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is an excerpt of the Describe response for the SentEvent:

```xml
...
<Properties>
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
    <Name>ID</Name>
    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
</Properties>
...
```

Comment: Thank you! What's the point of having a property that is not retrievable, but documented and present in WSDL? Is any replacement or a workaround that I can use? In fact, I need to export these events to an external system and need some unique identifier. Also, why Marketing Cloud does not allow to retrieve `SentEvent.ID` but allows `UnsubEvent.ID`? I'm just trying to get the logic behind this.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you, @RomanKlimenko. You'll find many properties that would be very handy to be able to access using SOAP that aren't retrievable. It can be quite frustrating. If you need a unique identifier, the logical primary key on SentEvents is a compound of SendID, ListID, BatchID and SubscriberID.